# vhosts.conf RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have my site in `/srv/http/site-dir/`, and in its root `.htaccess` with following:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /site-dir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It works that way, but now I would like to move those rules to httpd-vhosts.conf file, so what I need to change to have it working from there, and thus avoiding the use of .htaccess which I read is a bed practice if you have access to your main .conf file?

EDIT:
entered this into my httpd-vhosts.conf to try as suggested but without success.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/site-dir"
    ServerName project-site-dir.my
    ServerAlias www.project-site-dir.my

    Options -MultiViews -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^/site-dir/(.+)$ /site-dir/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/project-site-dir.my-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/project-site-dir.my-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this snippet in your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/site-dir"
    ServerName project-site-dir.my
    ServerAlias www.project-site-dir.my

    Options -MultiViews -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/project-site-dir.my-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/project-site-dir.my-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What URL did you use to test it?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/site-dir/home/exampletwo, also tell me do I have to specify somewhere AllowOverride or something?

Comment: If DocumentRoot is `/srv/http/site-dir` then URL should be `http://127.0.0.1/home/exampletwo`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it works now. So I read that %{REQUEST_FILENAME} isn't available in server context, as the server still does not now about local filesystem path, and that in that case %{LA-U:variable} should be used, how then this works?

Comment: I believe `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` should work but you can always use more reliable check using: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f`

Comment: Thanks. That was now even better, because until I did that change, I did not have my public/style.css rendered. ;)